# Is it possible to transform a SQL Code to a R Code?

Tags: r, database, evaluation

I got following problem: I got a Database and have to evaluate some Deltas e.g. I already computed this with SQL and it works well but now I need to try it with R and I didnt work much with R so I'm not quite sure if my problems are solvable with R. The best case would be if i can transform my sql code to a R code. Otherwise i will present my problem to you:

```
+----+------+------------+
| a  |  b   |     c      |
+----+------+------------+
| 10 |    2 | 31.01.2020 |
| 11 |    5 | 31.01.2020 |
| 10 |    3 | 31.01.2020 |
| 10 |    2 | 31.12.2019 |
| 11 |    4 | 31.12.2019 |
| 10 |   2  | 31.12.2019 |
+----+------+------------+
```

dput:

```
structure(list(a = c(10L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 10L), b = c(2L, 
5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L), c = c("31.01.2020", "31.01.2020", "31.01.2020", 
"31.12.2019", "31.12.2019", "31.12.2019")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

**delta**

```
+----+---+
| 10 | 1 |
| 11 | 1 |
+----+---+
```

It's my first time in this community so I hope you can see my picture. 
It's an example for my problem:

In the first step i need to summarize column b for the same date (c) and the same number in a). So the result for 31.12.2020 would be : 10= 5 and 11= 5 and the same for the 31.12.2019.

Until this point it works but in the next step I need to calculate an the delta of b) s.t.  column a) and c)

In other words: For the number 10 in a) i calculated 5 in 31.01.2020 in 31.12.2019 i calculated 4 for 10. Now i have to calculate 5-4, but it's not possible for me to program it.

So i hope some of you understand my problem and can help me to find a smart way i could solve this problem.

I would be very thankful if you can help me.

Comment: Welcome! The package `sqldf` allows you to use SQL code to operate on R data frames. This may be helpful if you have working SQL. Also, the data manipulation package `dplyr` is something that may be conceptually similar to how you think about it in SQL and therefore not hard to translate the code into R. Maybe those can be a starting place to explore.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with data.table. First convert `c` to a date column.

Then take the sum of `b` by each `(a, c)` group, then within the `a` groups of the resulting table, take the `diff` of this sum. The `diff` will be in the correct direction because `keyby` orders the results by the grouping columns.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, c := as.Date(c, format = '%d.%m.%Y')]

df[, .(bsum = sum(b)), keyby = .(a, c)
  ][, .(bsum_diff = diff(bsum)), by = a]
#     a bsum_diff
# 1: 10         1
# 2: 11         1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the package `dplyr`, try something like this:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(c_date = as.Date(c, format = "%d.%m.%Y")) %>% # convert to a Date in R
  group_by(a, c_date) %>% 
  summarize(b = sum(b)) %>% # sum grouped by a and c
  group_by(a) %>%
  arrange(c_date) %>% # sort on the date
  summarize(delta = diff(b)) # take the difference, grouped on a
```

Which will give:

```r
# A tibble: 2 x 2
      a delta
  <int> <int>
1    10     1
2    11     1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if is possible translate SQL to R code, but working with databases via R is not so hard. In a big picture: You need to set a SQL connection: DBI::dbconnect(). Next, with the function tbl() and the package dplyr you start to replicate a sql select statement. Here you can find more information:  https://db.rstudio.com